# Wine Issue in Running MSI file

Tags: windows, installation, ubuntu-14.04, wine

Issue that i am facing while running the msi from terminal is :

```
$wine msiexec /i openvpn--2.0.1.200.msi 

fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x1d1b1ee4) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x1e1fd098) stub
fixme:setupapi:SetupDiCallClassInstaller 25 0x3fec0 0x23f7f0
fixme:cacls:main This is dummy cacls, not performing ACL manipulations
fixme:cacls:main stub: "cacls" "installed.txt" "/G" "Everyone:F"
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"InstallDriver_CA" returned 1603
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"ExecuteAction" returned 1603
err:rpc:I_RpcGetBuffer no binding
err:rpc:I_RpcGetBuffer no binding
```

Any idea to debug or solve that issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure you're running it with wine? Try right clicking the file >> "Open with.." >> "Wine".

Comment: Yes Its "Wine Windows Program Loader"